# Jacobson radical of the $\mathbb{k}$-algebra $\mathbb{k}[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$ where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-of-algebras

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and $n\geq 1$. Consider the $\mathbb{k}$-algebra $A$ defined as:
$$A:=\mathbb{k}[x]/\langle x^n\rangle.$$
Then the Jacobson radical of $A$ (the intersection of all maximal ideals of $A$) is the ideal $\mathrm{rad}(A)=\big\langle \overline{x}\big\rangle$.

> Is the following proof correct ?

Let $f\in\mathbb{k}[x]$. Recall that the Jacobson radical has the following caracterization:

$$\overline{f}\in\mathrm{rad}(A) \Longleftrightarrow \forall g\in\mathbb{k}[x] \ \exists\,h\in\mathbb{k}[x]:\, \overline{(1-fg)h}=\overline{1}.$$

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $\overline{f}\in\mathrm{rad}(A)$. Then for each polynomial $g\in\mathbb{k}[x]$ we have:
$$\bigg(1-f(x)g(x)\bigg)h(x)=1+x^{n}w(x),\ \text{for some}\ w\in\mathbb{k}[x]$$
Looking at constants temrs we get
$$\big(1-f(0)g(0)\big)h(0)=1$$
we must have $f(0)g(0)\neq 1$, for each $g\in\mathbb{k}[x]$. This implies that 
$f(0)=0$, that is $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x$. Thus for some polynomial $q\in\mathbb{k}[x]$ we have:
 $$\overline{f(x)}=\overline{xq(x)}=\overline{x}\,\overline{q(x)}\in\langle \overline{x}\rangle.$$

($\Leftarrow$) Conversely, suppose that $\overline{f(x)}\in\langle \overline{x}\rangle$ and for each $g\in\mathbb{k}[x]$ we set 
$$h=1+fg+\cdots+f^{n-1}g^{n-1}$$
then
$$(1-fg)h=1-f^ng^n.$$
Hence
$$\overline{f}\in\mathrm{rad}(A) \Longleftrightarrow f^{n}g^{n}\in\langle x^n\rangle,\forall g\in\mathbb{k}[x]$$
but, we know by hypothesis that $\overline{f(x)}\in\langle \overline{x}\rangle$, then
$$\overline{f(x)^n}=\overline{f(x)}^{\,n}=\left(\overline{x}\overline{q(x)}\right)^n=\overline{x}^{\,n}\overline{q(x)}^{\,n}=\overline{x^n}\overline{q(x)}=\overline{0}\,\overline{q(x)}=\overline{0},$$
so $\ f^{n}\in\langle{x^n}\rangle$, finallly
$$f^{n}g^{n}\in\langle{x^n}\rangle,\ \forall\,g\in\mathbb{k}[x]$$
This implies that $\ \overline{f}\in\mathrm{rad}(A).$

Comment: The Jacobson radical contains all nilpotent elements. In particular it contains $x$ and the rest should be clear.

Comment: This is because $A$ is a commutative $\mathbb{k}$-algebra ?

Comment: It may be correct.  But it's too long.  You can find a much shorter proof if you remember that the ideals of $k[x]/(x^n)$ are precisely the (images of) the ideals of $k[x]$ that contain $(x^n)$ (and obviously maximal ideals correspond to maximal ideals).  If you think about it that way, you will be able to determine the Jacobson radical of any ring of the form $k[x]/(f(x))$, as long as you can factor $f$..

Comment: @C Monsour: Excellent! I was trying to prove that the jacobson radical of $\mathbb{k}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is the ideal $\langle p_{1}(x)\cdots p_{k}(x)\rangle$ where $p(x)=c\cdot p_{1}(x)^{d_1}\cdots p_{k}(x)^{d_k}$ is the primary decomposition of $p(x)$.